# Weird JavaScript issue

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome, syntax-error

So, I'm working with a JavaScript file. And for some reason, My browser is showing it as Chinese....

This is the actual JS file,

```
include('request_url.js');
//----jquery-plagins----
include('jquery-1.8.3.min.js');
include('jquery.ba-resize.min.js');
include('jquery.easing.js');
include('jquery.color.js');
include('gallery.js');
include('jquery.cycle.all.min.js');
include('jquery.fancybox.pack.js');
include('jquery.mousewheel.js');
include('uScroll.js');
//----bootstrap----
//----All-Scripts----
//include('forms.js');
include('jquery.mobilemenu.js');
include('scroll_to_top.js');
include('ajax.js.switch.js');
include('script.js');
//----Include-Function----
function include(url){ 
  document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="js/' + url + '"></script>'); 
  return false ;
}
```

However, When i'm in Chrome, and opposite click and go to "Inspect Element", and then go over to the Resources tab, and find my script. This is what it shows as..
[image: Weird JS Output]

Could anyone explain what's going on?

Comment: Sounds like you're using the wrong character encoding. Try saving your script in UTF-8.

Comment: What encoding are you using?

Comment: How would i change the encoding? (I'm using Notepad++)

Comment: Encoding > Encode in _yourChoiceHere_.

Comment: Thanks! That worked :). now I just need to change all the rest of my js files.

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to change the encoding from ANSII to UTF-8. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Was about time you did that :P